# Git push does not update files on server

Tags: git, github

I am new to using git, I have done the following as part of the setup. I have a dev server  on which we have the php code up and running. I converted the directory into git by `git init`. I have the same code copy on my local. which I used to transfer to dev via 'File transfer'.

Now since I converted my dev into a git ,I did same for local and added the dev git url as remote for the local and did a hard reset to match local as dev.

I changed a file and did `git push`, during that it gave me error `refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master` for which I followed an answer on stackoverflow and converted dev repo into bare repository

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

Now git push works , but the exact same file is not getting updated on dev server. What I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the remote working copy with `git push` anyway, and when you converted the remote repo to `bare` it doesn't have a working copy at all. One of usual practices is to push to a separate "master" repo and pull from it on each machine you need the working copy (including your dev server).

Comment: I see, so there is no way I can directly update files with `git push` . Also I am not sure if I did the right step converting the repo into bare. What would you suggest?

Comment: I suggest having a bare repo somewhere (maybe on the same machine) and manually pulling from it into the working copy on the dev server. I'm not sure what to do with the existing bare repo, maybe just unsetting `core.bare` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project to present the contents of a branch/revision/tag of a repo on a virtual FS. It's based on fuse and libgit2. It's in the very early stages at the moment but it can show you the files/directories in a revision and their contents. If you ask to use a branch, if the branch is moved, it will refresh the virtual FS on the fly. Just in case: early stages so no LFS, no submodules, no... whatever fancy feature you are thinking of? None of that. Just trees and blobs in git jargon.

https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod